# geom_tile no longer understands width and height outside aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since switching to `ggplot2 2.0.0` there are problems in defining the `width` and `height` of a tile outside the `aesthetics`. 
I used the `geom_tile` to create some kind of a heatmap and I wanted to have a little space between the tiles, so I used in the older version of `ggplot2` the `width=.9` and `height=.9` parameters, but this fails in the new version.

```
df <- data.frame(x=letters[1:10], y=rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=10), value=runif(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=value)) + geom_tile()
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=value)) + geom_tile(width=.9, height=.9)
```

The only way to get this working is by adding columns with width and height into the data frame and use the aesthetics. Is this supposed to work like this? Or do I miss something here?

```
df <- data.frame(x=letters[1:10], y=rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=10), 
                 value=runif(100), w=.9, h=.9)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=value)) + geom_tile(aes(width=w, height=h))
```

Comment: I suspect this might be an oversight from refactoring where the ellipses is passed to. You should report this.

Comment: I just reported it to `ggplot2` github page. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to add width and height values to dataframe. You can just move those two arguments to `aes()`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=value)) + geom_tile(aes(width=0.9, height=0.9))
```

Comment: Ok, but still it's weird, that `width` and `height` are not allowed as parameters of `geom_tile`. For instance, this (silly) example works: `ggplot(df, aes(xmin=x, ymin=y, fill=value)) + geom_rect(xmax=1,ymax=1)`

Comment: I can't find documentation for this behavior but in 2012 there was already such [problem caused by stat="identity"](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/651) and it was fixed. Maybe with the version 2.0.0 this problem has returned.

Comment: Didn't thought about this solution, thanks. But I am with Patrick, it is weird!